# How to import code from .exe project for unit test

Tags: c++, build, linker, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2015 to develop C++ app.

I have solution with two projects: one is the `.exe` project and another - project to test code via Boost Unit Tests.

Everything compiled, but linker fails to build second project. It says `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol`.

How to link second project to the code of the first project?

Comment: Have you added the second project as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import code from exe (i.e. link against exe), at least not easily. You can create a third project with the common code, either static or dynamic library, and let the exe and the units test  both depend and link against the library.

Another option would be to have everything in a single project, but that is more suitable for makefile or CMake project (and then have build targets "all" and "tests", for example).